# When I drag a TabBarController into storyboard,the bottomBar doesen't display

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

[image: it display a dark area]

as you can see,it displays a dark area.
how it can display icons,not a dark area?
Thank you for your answer

Comment: try this : click on the tabbar in your tabbarcontroller and check style in attribute inspector,change style black to default.

Comment: What is your Xcode version?

Comment: The style is default automatically,when I add an icon in it,it can display.Thank you at all events!

Comment: 7.2.2.And 7.1 appear this case ,too

Comment: I think this is a bug in xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

I had the problem till so you can change the colours like from above images. Just you can get the name of the tab bar items.

But when you are run it in device or simulator it should work.

Comment: Yes,when I add an icon in it,it can display.